# Will SO Career's free student filing rate continue in 2010?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, jobs, students, pricing

Right now, a student can file their resume on Stack Overflow Careers for free. Will they be able to do so after the price changes in 2010?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the *free* student filing will be available forever.

In fact, you will be able to "renew" your *free* student status every year, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> If you’re a student, a 1 year filing is free

Answer (score 1):

[Magic 8-ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_8-Ball) says: "Signs point to yes" -- or, ask [here](http://www.mattelgamefinder.com/demos.asp?demo=mb).